# Difference between single dash and double dash in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

Does anyone know what is the main difference between specifying an argparse agument with a single dash `-r` and a double dash `--r`?

I came across [this](http://argparsejl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/argparse.html#the-parse-args-function) Julia language argparse which classifies them as short and long but doesn't say exactly why you would use one over the other.

Comment: It depends on how you set it up! You wouldn't normally have a single letter for the long option; consider `-h` vs. `--help`, for example.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The long options like `--foo` come from the [GNU tradition](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html):

> GNU adds long options to these conventions. Long options consist of ‘--’ followed by a name made of alphanumeric characters and dashes. Option names are typically one to three words long, with hyphens to separate words. Users can abbreviate the option names as long as the abbreviations are unique.

It is very common to support both a short option `-f` and a long option `--foo`. The double dash `--` is used to distinguish a long option from a collection of short options. Usually, you can write both

```
go -a -b -c
```

or the condensed form

```
go -abc
```

That's *different*  from

```
go --abc
```

which is a different option.

Comment: Also, if a value is associated with the option there will be no space for the short form, e.g: `go -fvalue` compared with `go --foo=value`

Answer (score 10):

If following the usual conventions, the single dash arguments only consist of a single char, thus, `-abc` is identical to `-a -b -c`. Parameter names with double-dash are treated as whole words, so `--abc` is only a *single* parameter named `abc`.

Answer (score 1):

Although argparse supports the convention where multiple short options (using single-dash) can be specified using a single letter, e.g., `-abc` can be a shorter way to specify `-a -b -c`, argparse also allows unconventional use of words with single-dash options, which can render some short forms unusable due to ambiguity:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-ab', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-ac', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-b', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-c', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-bczzz', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-z', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

```
$ python3 parse.py -a
usage: parse.py [-h] [-ab] [-ac] [-b] [-c] [-bczzz] [-z]
parse.py: error: ambiguous option: -a could match -ab, -ac

$ python3 parse.py -ab
Namespace(ab=True, ac=False, b=False, bczzz=False, c=False, z=False)

$ python3 parse.py -abz
usage: parse.py [-h] [-ab] [-ac] [-b] [-c] [-bczzz] [-z]
parse.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -abz

$ python3 parse.py -bc
usage: parse.py [-h] [-ab] [-ac] [-b] [-c] [-bczzz] [-z]
parse.py: error: ambiguous option: -bc could match -b, -bczzz

$ python3 parse.py -cb
Namespace(ab=False, ac=False, b=True, bczzz=False, c=True, z=False)

$ python3 parse.py -bczz
usage: parse.py [-h] [-ab] [-ac] [-b] [-c] [-bczzz] [-z]
parse.py: error: ambiguous option: -bczz could match -b, -bczzz
```